# NVL function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I want to select all the data from the table employee and make an inner join with an other table for example:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
INNER JOIN Deparment ON Employee.Id_Department = Deparment.Deparment_Id 
    AND NVL('Mathematics', Deparment.Name);
```

When I execute that I get an error `ORA-00920`: Invalid relational operator, I think maybe the `nvl()` function is the problem here.

Comment: What do you want data from  AND NVL('Mathematics', Deparment.Name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a relational operator like `=, !=, <` after `NVL('Mathematics', Deparment.Name)`
as an example :

> AND NVL(Deparment.Name,'Mathematics')='Physics'

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the second condition in the join statement also `NVL()` function parameters misplaced.
Try this by assuming employee department name as `department_name` and change the script as per your need

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee
       inner join deparment
               ON employee.id_department = deparment.deparment_id
                  AND employee.department_name =
                      NVL(deparment.name, 'Mathematics');
```